# date in moment.js does not change when submit new transaction still save last date until refresh server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, momentjs

I am using `moment.js` to format date and save it in DB

Schema code

```
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    transactionTime: {
        type: Date,
        default: moment().toDate(),
    },
```

front code

```
<td>{moment(transaction.transactionTime).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}</td>
```

but when I submit a transaction the date is not updated for real-time I send it I must refresh the server to update the date

[image]

Comment: can you know me how frequest did you insert the data. This date format is not display milliseconds. I suggest you should add new column of milliseconds which shows the time in milliseconds and it says that how much difference among each insertions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `moment().toDate()` as the default, the default value is set to the date and time when you started the application and stays constant. What you want to do is to rather specify a function that returns the current date, which would result in the function being executed at each insertion, thus getting the actual current time:

```js
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    transactionTime: {
        type: Date,
        default: () => moment().toDate(),
    },
...
```

Comment: Fantastic, you are right it is working well now